# System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'CRM.Models.SiteSettings' threw an exception.'

Tags: c#, unit-testing

When I add a reference to unit test, it fails to initialize a static class that is in the target project that I want to test.

I tried to place the code separately, like this:

```
string s=SiteSettings.CRMConnectionString;
```

But still, I got the same error.

```
public static class SiteSettings{
  public static string CRMConnectionString = "dads";
}
```

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 
>   'CRM.Models.SiteSettings' threw an exception.'   Inner Exception
>   NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an  instance of an
>   object.

What changes do I need to make in order for my unit test against my target project?

Comment: Try rebuilding your project and manually move it to the test project. This frequently happens when you load library with updated source.

Comment: Rebuilding didnt work. What do you mean by moving it to the test project? Do you mean placing it inside the test project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because one of my class properties included this:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmailDataBase"].ConnectionString;
```

When initalizing, it couldnt find  the connection string. Hence, the error was generated.